Quoted expression in Jinja2
ChatGPT told me that:
In Jinja2, if an expression is enclosed in quotes (single or double), it is treated as a literal string, and the entire content, including the expression, will be output as-is. Jinja2 does not parse or evaluate expressions within quoted strings.
However I tested the following template:
{% set name = "Jason" -%}
Name: "{{ name }}"

The output is
Name: "Jason"

While according to ChatGPT it should be:
Name: {{ name }}

So is ChatGPT wrong? What is the behavior of double/single quote in jinja2?


So is ChatGPT wrong?

No.
When you write:
Name: "{{ name }}"

The quotes are not part of the Jinja template expression. They are literal text in your document. Jinja only evaluates expressions within {{...}} markers. If you had written this:
Name: {{ "name" }}

Jinja would interpret "name" as a literal string and the output would be:
Name: name

And if you had written:
Name: "{{ "name" }}"

The output would be:
Name: "name"


Thanks, so ONLY the content enclosed by {{ and }}, {% and %}, {# and #} is identified and parsed, all other content is output directly, correct?

That is correct.
